# SQL server : How to seperate XML nodes in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have three column in my table with one column of XML type. I want to show different nodes of the XML data in different rows. Like,

```
Col1      Col2         Col3
12        ABC          <Interactions><interaction id='2' name='A'/><interaction id='3' name='B'/></Interactions>
```

How to show different interaction in different rows? like,

```
Row1 :  12    ABC   2   A
Row2 :  12    ABC   3   B
```

Thanks!
Ank

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    A.Col1
    ,A.Col2
    ,Split.interaction.value('@id', 'INT') AS [ID]
    ,Split.interaction.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS [Name]
 FROM  
 (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM  #Tablexml
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Col3.nodes ('/Interactions/interaction') AS Split(interaction);
```

[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/122842)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    T.Col1, T.Col2,
    C.N.value('@id', 'int') as ID,
    C.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name
from Table1 as T
    outer apply T.Col3.nodes('Interactions/interaction') as C(N)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59899/1)</kbd>**